# Same footnote in each page

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, footer, footmisc, xfootnote

[image: Graphical Exposition of my problem]I would like to write the same footnote in every page of the document. The footnote is 'Footnote of the day'. How am I able to print this same footnote in each page?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That looks more like a footer than a footnote. See the package `fancyhdr`.

Comment: You can add a footnore use `\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\footnotetext[]{...}}` for every page except the first.

Comment: I want to print the same footnote at the end of each page. I have edited my post adding a graphical exposition which may help you to understand my problem.

Comment: Please post your code, what you tried till now as `MWE`, i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Pieter van Oostrum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/113546/pieter-van-oostrum) said in the comments, you can try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Default \headrulewidth is 0.4pt
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} % Default \footrulewidth is 0pt

% center of footer
\cfoot{\thepage}

% LE: left of even pages
% LO: left of odd pages
\fancyfoot[LE,LO]{\footnotesize{`Footnote of the day'}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution is as close as to my requirement. But there is a slight problem. As I run your code, it prints the footnote and the page no. in same line. I want a vertical space between the footnote and the page no. What should I do for that?

Comment: A quick way is that you change your cfoot like this `\cfoot{\quad\\ \quad \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ \thepage}`.  By the way, if you want to change the length of the horizontal rule, you can use `\renewcommand\footrule{\hrule width 0.6\textwidth}`